# $*$-homomorphic image of approximate identities and multipliers

Tags: dynamical-systems, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, amenability

I am currently reading through Claire Anantharaman-Delaroche's paper "Amenability and exactness for dynamical systems and their $C^*$-algebras". Arxiv-link: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005014.

In the proof of Theorem $4.6 \ (1)\Rightarrow (2)$ it is mentioned that the image of an approximate identity is an approximate identity of multipliers. How is this realized?

Thank you

Added details:
Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and let $G$ denote a locally compact Hausdorff group. Given a closed two-sided ideal $I$ in a $G$-$C^*$-algebra $A$, we denote by $\phi_I$ the $*$-homomorphism induced to the reduced crossed products by the natural inclusion of $I$ into $C(X,I)$, i.e. $\phi_I: I \rtimes_r G \to C(X,I)\rtimes_r G$.

The following quote from the paper is causing me troubles: "Given an approximate unit $(u_\lambda)$ in $I$, the net $(\phi_I(u_\lambda))$ is an approximate unit of multipliers in $C(X,I)\rtimes_r G$".

Comment: In general, a $\ast$-homomorphism doesn't map approximate identities to approximate identities (think of the zero homomorphism). So please extract all necessary information from this preprint instead of just giving the link.

Comment: @MaoWao Of course! I hope that the added details help clarifying the issue.

Comment: What you need is that this map is non-degenerate.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you. I suppose that the image of an approximate identity is always an approximate identity in the image. Non-degeneracy then implies that it becomes an a.i. in the full codomain. However, is this property clear in my case? If so, what is the point in stating the result in terms of multipliers?